# Need a regex to be used in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex which will allow me to

1) allow only numbers **[solved]**

2) decimal up to 2 places **[solved]**

3) allow only 1 zero at the beginning example : '0.12' **=> need help on this**

4) not allow only zeros example : '0000' **=> need help on this**

Below is the regex I currently have which allows only numbers and 2 places after a decimal:

`Regex:  /^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?\s*$/g`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are `01`, `0.00` and `1.` valid?

Comment: **0.00 is valid**, _01 and 1. are not valid_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you're looking for an ***or*** in your expression, zero or any number starting with `1-9`.

```js
const re = /^(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/

;[
    '0',
    '00',
    '10',
    '010',
    '123',
    '123.',
    '123.0',
    '123.00',
    '123.000',
    '0.1',
    '0.10',
    '0.100',
    '00.10'
]
    .forEach(
        v => console.log(re.test(v) ? '✓' : '✗', v)
    )
```

I omitted the leading and trailing whitespace matchers for brevity - but generally speaking if you're allowing this it might also be a little cleaner to [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) the input before working with it.  Also note that you likely need to not match the period if there are no decimals after it.

- [Detailed walkthrough on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JkHuiE/1)